# Check if file exists in internal directory

Tags: android

Im checking if a file excists in a directory. If not it should download it.

```
    File file = new File(mediadir, _name);

    if(file.exists()) {
        Log.i("FILE EXISTS", _name);
    } else {
        Log.i("DOWNLOAD", _name);
        new Download().execute(context, name, "http://192.168.2.136:8080/rest/transfer/"+ linkid +"/"+ username +"/" + json_data.getString("ID"));
}
```

But **file.exists()** is always **true**

*the file does not exists on there*

I run this right before the file.exists()

```
        File mediadir = getDir("tvr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (mediadir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = mediadir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                new File(mediadir, children[i]).delete();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Then your file exists?

Comment: "the file does not exists on there" -- somewhere, you are making a mistake. Either `mediadir` and `_name` do not point to where you think they do, or you are not looking in the right place when you are manually inspecting the filesystem. `exists()` does not lie, so Android thinks that the file exists.

Comment: have you added <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to your manifest? WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE in case your file is located in device memory. You possibly do not have the permission to modify that file, that's why exists() returns true after you try to delete the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using isFile() instead?

Comment: mm, let me try this, I have not! I think this is going to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  for (File f : myDir.listFiles()) {
  //Do your stuf
   String name = f.getName();
  //Here you will get file you have already stored in directory.

  }
```